# Coordinate time -- proper time plot in Schwarzschild orbit

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, computational-physics, simulations, time-dilation

I'm solving the Schwarzschild geodesics numerically, and I'm wondering if the result I'm getting makes physical sense.
The parameter of the path $x^{\mu}=(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ is the proper time $\tau$, and when I graph the coordinate time $t$ against the proper time, I get a really straight, linear relation, which, considering the wild oscillation in the radial coordinate (ie: 6+ oscillations between 6.5 and 15 $GM$), I have a hard time believing.

Granted, the coordinate time is always greater than the proper time, so time-dialation IS taking place.

Below I've attached the 2 corresponding plots.

[image: Asymptotic coordinate time vs proper time]

[image: Radial coordinate vs proper time]

For reference, I'm integrating the equations from the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Geodesic_equation with maple's dsolve(numeric), rk45 .

Comment: I'm using the equations from the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Geodesic_equation ,
and solving them via maple's dsolve(numeric), rk45.

Comment: Calculate the maximum and minimum orbital speed as a fraction of $c$, and the maximum and minimum gravitational potential as a fraction of $c^2$, to see whether the time dilation should vary much. It looks like there is a slight wobble in the straightness of the plot.

Comment: Without the initial conditions, it’s hard to know.

Comment: For what it's worth, my initial conditions were $x^{\mu}(0)=(0,6.5,\pi /2, 0)$ and $ v^{\mu}(0) = (1.38,0,0, 0.088) $, with $c=G=M=1$ .

Comment: The initial conditions and units belong *in the question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s ignore the kinematic time dilation and estimate the gravitational time dilation. The dilation factor, approximately $1+\frac{GM}{rc^2}$ at large $r$, varies between $1+\frac{1}{6.5}\approx 1.15$ to $1+\frac{1}{15}\approx 1.07$. That’s about a 4% variation around the average, and it seems consistent with the slight visible wobble around the plot’s straightness.

If you want to see a larger effect, use an eccentric orbit that gets closer to the event horizon.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Combined_effect_of_velocity_and_gravitational_time_dilation) has an exact formula for the time dilation factor, taking both kinematic time dilation and gravitational time dilation into account, and not using the large-$r$ approximation.